# Using a dictionary as a variable

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
def Stats(self):
    Stats = {}
    for i in self.ExpTable:
      Stats[i] = self.GetLvl(i)
    for i in Stats:
      print i + ":" + str(Stats[i])
```

I need to be able to use ExpTable as a variable when defining as i need to use other dict's later on all in format of {"String":Integer}

```
def Stats(self, {ExpTable}):
    pass
```

something like this which works using it as a dictionary but being able to change dictonaries

Comment: Could you please elaborate and clarify? Pretend we can't read your mind and need more than two sentences.

Comment: Are you asking, how do you pass a dictionary to a function? You do it the same way you pass any variable. `def Stats(self, myDict):`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the `Stats` method to take a dictionary as an argument, but to use the object's `ExpTable` attribute if none is provided.

```
def Stats(self, d=None):
    if d is None:
        d = self.ExpTable
    new_stats = {}
    for i in d:
        new_stats[i] = self.GetLvl(i)
    for i in new_stats:
        print i + ":" + str(new_stats[i])
```